# How to stop Overleaf adding the ending symbols to $ and [

Tags: editors, sharelatex, overleaf

In Overleaf/Sharelatex, whenever I type a `$` or a `[`, it will automatically follow up with the corresponding ending symbol. So instead `$$` or `[]` will appear. How do I stop this from happening, besides by rage-throwing my computer off a bridge? I prefer what appears to be what I typed.

While I'm at it, is there a way to turn off the suggestion window that pops up while typing?

Side question: what is the terminology for an ending symbol that pairs with a beginning symbol? Knowing that would have made it easier for me to search for an answer or to phrase this question.

Comment: A closing or right or paired delimiter?

Comment: I was about to suggest rage-throwing your computer off a bridge...

Answer (score 14):

Click on `Menu` search `Auto-close Brackets` select `Off`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That was so easy, but I was looking in only the wrong places. Oops.

Comment: @SomaticCustard You're welcome, it happens :)